# Python: Allow the positional argument to be specified last or write it first in the help output when using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

This code

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('target', help='Specifiy who to attack!')

magic = ['fireball', 'heal', 'microwave']
parser.add_argument('-m', '--magic', nargs='*',
                    choices=magic,
                    help=('Magic'))
parsed_arguments = parser.parse_args()
```

Produces this help output

```
usage: Example.py [-h]
                  [-m [{fireball,heal,microwave} [{fireball,heal,microwave} ...]]]
                  target

positional arguments:
  target                Specifiy who to attack!

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m [{fireball,heal,microwave} [{fireball,heal,microwave} ...]], --magic [{fireball,heal,microwave} [{fireball,heal,microwave} ...]]
                        Magic
```

I think the help output is confusing and makes it look like the target should be specified last, which however does not work: `python example.py -m fireball troll` gives `argument -m/--magic: invalid choice: 'troll'`.

I realize the grammar of the language becomes ambiguous, but it would still be possible to tell that as there should exist one word (target) last in the sentence `troll` is not an argument to the `-m` option.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to let the positional argument be specified last without beating argparse to much?
2. Is there a way to let the argparse help output indicate that target should indeed be specified first?

Comment: a common practice in POSIX systems is to use `--` to denote the end of options. Example: `command -m something somethingelse -- target`

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful and indeed `-m fireball -- troll` works. I would still like answers to the questions in the OP. I guess 2 is most important as I think it would valuable to the users of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned in a comment, the standard methods on POSIX systems to denote the end of options is to separate the arguments and options by `--`.

As for the second question: You might have to create your own HelpFormatter to achieve this, see [formatter-class](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#formatter-class). You might be able to inherit from the default formatter and override only the necessary functions to generate the usage line.